# Install libvips on golang docker container

Tags: go, tensorflow2.0, vips, libvips

How to install libvips on a docker container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My take on this .

```
    FROM ubuntu:20.04
    
    RUN mkdir /app
            
    COPY imgApp /app
    
    ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
            build-essential \
            wget \
            git \
            pkg-config
    
    RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip python3-setuptools \
                           python3-wheel
    RUN pip3 install meson ninja
    
    RUN apt-get install -y \
            libexpat1-dev \
            librsvg2-dev \
            libpng-dev \
            libjpeg-dev \
            libwebp-dev \
            libexif-dev \
            liblcms2-dev \
            libglib2.0-dev \
            liborc-dev \
            libgirepository1.0-dev \
            gettext 
    
    ARG VIPS_VER=8.14.2
    ARG VIPS_DLURL=https://github.com/libvips/libvips/releases/download
    RUN cd /usr/local/src \
            && wget ${VIPS_DLURL}/v${VIPS_VER}/vips-${VIPS_VER}.tar.xz \
            && tar xf vips-${VIPS_VER}.tar.xz \
            && cd vips-${VIPS_VER}
            && meson setup build --buildtype=release \
            && cd build \
            && meson compile \
            && meson test \
            && meson install
    RUN ldconfig
            
    RUN export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/vips/lib
```

Hope someone will better this in future.

Comment: You don't need libgif (libvips comes with its own GIF decoder), and you can skip libgirepository1.0-dev too if you pass -Dintrospection=disabled to meson. Otherwise, nice job!

Comment: This is amazing! Exactly what I've been looking for. I searched for hours and could not believe there was no guide on how to install a specific version of libvips in Docker. Thank you so much! This must be included in the official documentation

Comment: @afrish happy to read